# what does "i" in square brackets do in CSS selector?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I just discovered this selector in chrome developer console as an "user agent stylesheet":

```
input[type="radio" i], input[type="checkbox" i] { ... }
```

what does the "i" do? I've never seen such construction in selector before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Case-Sensitive Attribute Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case) which has been introduced in the Selectors Level 4 working draft:

> `E[foo="bar" i]`
>
> An E element whose `foo` attribute value is exactly equal to any (ASCII-range) case-permutation of `bar`.

> ### 6.3. Case-sensitivity
>
> By default case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors depends on the document language. To match attribute values case-insensitively regardless of document language rules, the attribute selector may include the identifier `i` before the closing bracket (`]`). When this flag is present, UAs must match the attribute's value case-insensitively within the ASCII range.
>
> ***Example 13***
>
> The following rule will style the frame attribute when it has a value of hsides, whether that value is represented as hsides, HSIDES, hSides, etc. even in an XML environment where attribute values are case-sensitive.
>
> ```css
> [frame=hsides i] { border-style: solid none; }
> ```

It's worth noting that browser support for this at present will be very poor if not non-existent. Existing CSS implementations which do make use of this selector are possibly using external JavaScript libraries to imitate the Selectors Level 4 definition(s).

Comment: What's the browser support for this? Doesn't seem to work in the latest Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/zn6ygofb/

Comment: @Nit probably very little. The Selectors Level 4 Working Draft also defines a parent selector (`E! > F`) which has been [in demand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for a very long time. I've added a bit about browser support to my answer.

Comment: @Nit: Browser support is covered in the duplicate link, which, incidentally, was where James encountered the [css4] tag [some time ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/css4-tag-misnomer-or-useful/293623#293623) :P